# disable built-in flymake completely

Tags: flymake

I'm running emacs-29.1 on ubuntu-23.10 (installed from https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntuhandbook1/emacs/ubuntu/), and it has `flymake` built-in and default to running. There are similar questions for disabling it for specific backends or converting to `flycheck` (not interested at the moment), but I would like to disable it completely for all major/minor modes without having to explicitly remove hooks from various places (ess, python-mode, etc).

Short of the nuclear option (`mv -t /path/to/SAVE_or_DELETE/ /usr/share/emacs/29.1/lisp/progmodes/flymake*`, and accept warnings/errors about package-not-found), is there a global option for just disabling it? I can't find it in `customize`.

Comment: Flymake is not enabled by default, it may be enabled by Elgot or other packages. You can check this with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: Certainly ... but it is rather entwined within the ubuntuhandbook1 setup. I've tried moving the `.el`/`.elc` files, but other portions of the emacs start-up depend on it. I see no ability to remove all hooks for it. @TianshuWang

Comment: Further, `snap install emacs` does the same thing: flymake is installed and enabled globally by default. I haven't compiled emacs-29.1 manually, but I suspect this is not specific to `ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/emacs` nor the snap package.

Comment: Try adding `(flymake-mode -1)` in your init file. If it does not work, try `(add-hook 'find-file-hook (lambda () (flymake-mode -1)))`.